# YUI editor content save in database PHP

Tags: php, yui, rich-text-editor

I am using YUI editor. I tried to fetch the `textarea` value and save it in database, but i am not able to do so. Here is my code.

```
@$titleidz=$_POST['title'];
@$contentidz=$_POST['editor'];
if($titleidz && $contentidz)
{
include_once('../config/config.php');
$q= "insert  into tbl_page(title, content) values('$titleidz', '$contentidz')" ;
$result=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());    
<form action="" name="form" method="post">
<table style="table-layout: fixed;width:100%">
<tr><input class="input_text" type="text" size="50" name="title" placeholder="Enter Your Title" id="title"></td><td><span style="color:red" id="errTitle"></span></td></tr>
<tr><td><textarea id="editor" name="editor" rows="20" cols="75">fffffffff</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align="middle"><input type="submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>

(function() {
var Dom = YAHOO.util.Dom,
    Event = YAHOO.util.Event;

var myConfig = {
    height: '300px',
    width: '990px',
    animate: true,
    dompath: true,
    focusAtStart: true
};

var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('editor', myConfig);
myEditor.render();

})();
```

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: Side note: the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: this is not a normal textarea, i am using yui rich text editor

Comment: I understand that. Not sure what your point is?  It's still vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Again. What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: my code works perfect with input field but doesn't save the value for the textarea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call `saveHTML()` method for yui editor before your form submission to get the value then save it :

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on('somebutton', 'click', function() {
    //Put the HTML back into the text area
    myEditor.saveHTML();

    //The var html will now have the contents of the textarea
    var html = myEditor.get('editor').value;
});
```

then save in your database the content of the variable `html`

see [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with the input field without YUI editor?

Try to add var_dump($_POST) at the beggining of your code. That way you will see what content was posted to the server. It's basic debugging :)

Comment: I have checked `var_dump($_POST)`, but i din't get the text that i had written in textarea